# Throughput setting in Memaslap (a memcached testing tool) does not seem to work

Tags: memcached, libmemcached

I am testing the response time of memcached by using memaslap. The memaslap is installed in a lxc (container with 1 core and 1 cache way), and the memcached is installed in another lxc (7 cores with 19 cache ways). I use the default settings for memcached (cachesize = 64M and maxconnection = 1024).

Here is my memaslap settings `memaslap -s 192.168.122.123:11211 -S 10s -x 1000000 -T 1 -P 10k`.

Then it outputs that `Run time: 17.8s Ops: 1000000 TPS: 56306 Net_rate: 57.2M/s`.

However, when I use another throughput setting:`memaslap -s 192.168.122.123:11211 -S 10s -x 1000000 -T 1 -P 100k`.

Then it reprints the almost same result `Run time: 17.9s Ops: 1000000 TPS: 55760 Net_rate: 56.5M/s`.

Does anyone can tell the reason why throughtput setting does not work? My testing platfrom is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 v4 @ 1.70GHz， one cpu socket with 8 physical cores, not supporting hyper-thread, and 16G memory.

Answer (score 0):

Using `-P|--tps` sets "expected TPS" per connection, while number of connections is set with `-c|--concurrency`.

Each thread (number of threads set with `-T|--threads`) will open `concurrency`/`threads` connections and watch each connections throughput, `tps`/`concurrency`.

Now, when performing the load test, and the actual throughput exceeds the expected throughput, the current thread will sleep for 10µs.

That's all.